# communication between page

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a page (`Page A`) where user can send email to others, then user should can choose the recipients.

So when user click the "Choose contact" button in `Page A`, a new browser page (`Page B`) will open where all their contacts in the database will be displayed using the check box list.

Then the user can choose the contacts he want, when he click "OK" button in `Page B`,the `Page A` will close. Then how should I get, in `Page A`, the contacts the user chosen over at `Page B`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. I believe the simplest is a pure JavaScript solution.

Create a JS function on the parent page that will handle the contacts that are received. When the submit/finish button is clicked on the child page, pass the selected contacts to the parent by using

```
window.opener.SomeFunctionName(arrayOfContactsOrContactIDs);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you indeed open a new window, you can use the `window.opener` to talk with the parent window.

I would suggest, though, that you use an ajax call to fetch the contacts and display them in the current page (*perhaps in an overlay*).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [AJAX ToolKit Modal Popup](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can save contact in a session variable for example!

Comment: Well,I save the contact in session when user cick "ok" in pageB,but how do pageA know that the user have complete the work,and he should add the contact in paegA?

Comment: Inside Page_Load you can retrieve session variable.